# How do I change the speed of my enemy sprite?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am a beginner programmer programming a platformer game, and I don't know how to change the speed of the sprite. Can someone help me?

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.images_right = []
        self.images_left = []
        self.counter = 0
        self.index = 0
        self.direction = -1
        for num in range(1,2):
            img_right = pygame.image.load(f'img/Base pack/Enemies/walk/slimeWalk{num}.png')
            img_right = pygame.transform.scale(img_right, (40, 20))
            img_left = pygame.transform.flip(img_right, True, False)
            self.images_right.append(img_right)
            self.images_left.append(img_left)
        self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.width = self.image.get_width()
        self.height = self.image.get_height()

        self.move_direction = 1
        self.move_counter = 0

    def update (self):
        self.rect.x += self.move_direction
        self.move_counter += 1
        if self.move_counter > 50:
            self.move_direction *= -1
            self.move_counter *= -1
            self.direction *= -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just multiply the direction by a speed factor when adding it to the object's position:

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # [...]
        
        self.speed = 5

    def update (self):
        self.rect.x += self.move_direction * self.speed

        # [...]
```

Comment: thank you, that helps so much. However, when setting self.speed to less than 1, the sprite does not move back and forth, it moves one direction and pauses.

Answer (score 0):

To decrease the speed of the sprite, I modified my code:

```
self.heart_beat += 1
if self.heart_beat % 3 == 0:
    self.rect.x += (self.move_direction * self.speed)
    self.move_counter += 1
if self.move_counter > 50:
    self.move_direction *= -1
    self.direction *= -1
    self.move_counter *= -1
```